# Redirect specific image to another specific image htaccess - WordPress

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I have a WordPress website, where I want to specifically redirect one image to another image. I have tried using a redirection plugin and while this has worked for web pages, it didn't seem to work for my image and it suggested that I needed to add the redirect to my .htaccess file.

So I have tried adding the following:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
# The directives (lines) between "BEGIN WordPress" and "END WordPress" are
# dynamically generated, and should only be modified via WordPress filters.
# Any changes to the directives between these markers will be overwritten.
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
RewriteBase /
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
RewriteRule ^wp-content/uploads/2021/03/ImageA.jpg$ ^wp-content/uploads/2021/03/imageB.jpg [L,R=301]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

However, this still doesn't seem to work. Is there something that I'm missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the original URL/image exists as a physical file then the redirection plugin will not work since the WordPress engine is never initiated.

> ```
> RewriteRule ^wp-content/uploads/2021/03/TrackClosed.jpg$ ^wp-content/uploads/2021/03/LightningTalks.jpg [L,R=301]
> ```

There are a few things potentially wrong with this:

1. By placing this after the WordPress front-controller it is only going to be processed if the original URL still exists as a physical file. If the source URL does not exist as a physical file then this directive needs to go *before* the WP front-controller (ie. *before* the `# BEGIN WordPress` section).
2. The target URL, starting with `^` is not valid. You should be explicit and start the destination URL with a slash (ie. root-relative). Although this is not strictly necessary since the `RewriteBase` directive is defined.
3. Should this really be an external 3xx redirect or an internal rewrite?
4. You should avoid editing the code inside the `# BEGIN WordPress` block since WP itself tries to main this section and any customisations could be overwritten.

Try the following instead, at the top of the `.htacess` file, *before* the `# BEGIN WordPress` section:

```
RewriteRule ^wp-content/uploads/2021/03/ImageA\.jpg$ /wp-content/uploads/2021/03/ImageB.jpg [R=301,L]
```

This "redirects" `/wp-content/uploads/2021/03/ImageA.jpg` (case-sensitive match) to `/wp-content/uploads/2021/03/ImageB.jpg`. To change this to an *internal* rewrite then simply remove the `R=301` flag.

There is no need to repeat the `RewriteEngine` directive.

Test with a 302 (temporary) redirect first. You will likely need to clear your browser cache before testing.